# How can I align Date modified with Date last saved?

Tags: 2010, date-time, save

I still have this problem with Sharepoint 2010 and Windows 7, i.e. Excel or Word documents edited from within Sharepoint display an outdated Date modified in Windows Explorer view.
However, the 'Date last saved' is correct.

Hence, would it be possible to align the document's 'Date modified' with its 'Date last saved", perhaps with a Powershell script? The script would fix the dates of all documents of a folder (and optionally subfolders).

Comment: My organization applied the SharePoint Service Pack 2 recently and the initial problem was fixed, i.e. Date modified and Date last saved are now consistent.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:

```
Function Do-WhatOPAskedFor
{
    param
    (
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPList] $list
    )

    # Please note that this is a bad way of getting all items from the list!
    $items = $list.Items
    $items | Align-DateFields "Modified" "Date Last Saved"
}

Function Align-DateFields
{
    param
    (       
        [string] $dateModifiedFieldName,
        [string] $dateLastSavedFieldName,
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true,ValueFromPipelineByPropertyName=$true)]
        [Microsoft.SharePoint.SPListItem] $item
    )

    begin {}
    process
    {
        [DateTime]$dateLastSaved = $item[$dateLastSavedFieldName];
        $item[$dateModifiedFieldName] = $dateLastSaved;
        $item.Update();
    }
    end {}
}
```

`Do-WhatOPAskedFor` will do what you asked for; I'm just bad at naming functions.  What it does is takes a SharePoint list, enumerates its items, and sends each item to be processed by a function.  The function `Align-DateFields` takes a SharePoint list item, extracts what's in the specified field, and saves it to another field.

Let me know if you need any further details!

EDIT:

Here's some code to load up the SharePoint list and pass it to the function above:

```
# Do this if you can load the SharePoint module (e.g., are in a SharePoint Management Shell)
$web = Get-SPWeb http://yourwebsitehere;
$list = $web.Lists["Your list title here"];
Do-WhatOPAskedFor $list;
$web.Dispose();

# Do this if you only have a regular PowerShell shell:
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint") | Out-Null;
$site = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://yoursitecollectionhere");
$web = $site.AllWebs | Where { $_.Title -eq "Your site title here" } | Select -First 1
$list = $web.Lists["Your list title here"];
Do-WhatOPAskedFor $list;
$site.Dispose();
```

In the first one, we use the functions in the SharePoint PowerShell module to grab the `SPWeb`, extract the `SPList` and pass it to the function.  In the second, we have to load the `Microsoft.SharePoint` assembly, instantiate an `SPSite` object which contains the `SPWeb`, grab the `SPWeb`, extract the `SPList`, and pass it to the function.

Comment: Thanks. But, how I do I invoke the Do-WhatOPAskedFor function?

Comment: If available, you can use the SharePoint Management Shell.  If not, you can load up `Microsoft.SharePoint` as an assembly into a PowerShell shell.  Then, copy and paste those functions, get a reference to the SharePoint list, and run it like any other PowerShell function