# Correct date/time metadata for files on sharepoint based on file information from Word/Excel

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, metadata, sync

Maybe someone has a good idea for the following problem.

In our company, we just went through a take-over of our Microsoft 365 domain. During that process, all data from the old Sharepoint was downloaded to a NAS and later uploaded from the NAS to the new Sharepoint. Although this is basically good, all files within the folder structure of File Explorer (Windows) are now displayed with a wrong date and time of when they were created/edited.

When Office documents are opened with the corresponding app (Word, Excel, etc.) and are not changed/saved, the date and time of some additional (usually hidden) columns in File Explorer get updated with the relevant date/time. Unfortunately, that's getting undone, if the "Free up space" option from OneDrive is used. Furthermore, it doesn't work for PDF documents.

[image: Columns before opening the file]

[image: Columns after opening the file]

Therefore, my question is, whether it is somehow possible with a powershell script or with a tool to adjust the last changed date/time from the document information tags (metadata). Of course, the action itself must not be noticed as a change by Sharepoint - otherwise it would not help us.

If I'd have to run a script/tool for each folder separately, it would be ok, but I'd prefer to be able to process all subfolders at once.

I found [this post](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/118047/how-can-i-align-date-modified-with-date-last-saved), but because it is related to Sharepoint 2010, I doubt that the given solution is still suitable. Because I'm not an administrator of the Sharepoint site, I can't test it myself.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Sidenote:
Upon my initial question at https://stackoverflow.com I got a suggestion to ask here.

Answer (score 0):

How many documents do you need to process?
Reason for asking: there is an app that provides the requested functionality to use the create/modify dates present within Office/pdf SharePoint files as SharePoint creation and modified dates. The use of the app does not result in new document versions and keeps the existing modified by fields. However, the app is developed for bulk changes (100000+ files) so would be overkill for a small data set.

Comment: There are 'only' about 30'000 documents. So according to your post, the suggested app would indeed be an overkill.

Comment: That is indeed a limited number of files. This may mean there are several more apps/scripts (e.g., PowerShell) suitable for the task.

FYI: I am not aware of other apps that can offer the required functionality:
- authenticate to multiple sites
- select files with invalid dates (avoid processing items multiple times)
- download the 30k files
- extract create and modify dates from different file formats
- change the SharePoint created and modified dates (in the correct format) without adding a new document version
- generate logs